# Christoffel symbols formula

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, notation

I am somewhat new to Einstein's summation notation. I understand it, but am not yet confident if I expand it correctly. I need a formula for the Christoffel symbols of the second kind that doesn't use this notation, but I am having a hard time finding it anywhere online. Could anyone please provide either the formula or a link to it? It would be very helpful.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Thank you! Do I understand correctly that this formula uses the summation notation? My question was for the formula without it. I understand, a silly question, but I just wanted to make sure I am properly following the summation procedure while learning it.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Thanks again. Yes, this is all very simple after one gets the correct procedure. So my question is if someone would write down the full formula with all the sums and partial derivatives just for fun and help in addition to +25 points for the answer :) - or provide a link.

Comment: Outstanding. Thanks so much! Would it be too much to ask you to please just copy/paste it in an answer? The reason is that I cannot get the LaTex from a comment. Not a huge deal, but it would save me some time and effort plus I'd be able to properly mark it as helpful :) It's fine either way. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The summation convention is simple: a repeated index (usually downstairs and upstairs) is implicitly summed. All you have to do is add a summation sign for each repeated index. So if the formula with the Einstein convention is

$$\Gamma^a{}_{bc} = \frac12 g^{ad}(g_{db,c}+g_{dc,b}-g_{bc,d})$$

you just put a summation over $d$:

$$\Gamma^a{}_{bc} = \sum_{d=0}^3 \frac12 g^{ad}(g_{db,c}+g_{dc,b}-g_{bc,d}).$$

I'm summing from $0$ to $3$ assuming the usual four dimensional spacetime; of course, the sum should run over all the dimensions.

Checking your understanding is good, but I really recommend getting used to the convention as soon as possible. It makes your life so much easier when you instantly read a repeated index as a dot product.

Comment: Where "repeated" means used in two values that are multiplied on one side of the equation, correct? Two values added with the same index would not be a summation. Or if the indexes on different sides like $a_j=b_j$ also no summation. Am I getting this right?

Comment: Yes, repeated means present in two factors of a product.